# Impress presentation format problem

Tags: libreoffice

I have install Ubuntu 15.10 and am using libreoffice impress office version 5.1.1.3 and using windows fonts in Ubuntu, still am facing a problem am created some PPT  also am saved this files .pptx, but when am open this files in windows 7 then some contains and table messed up am also try to update libreoffice but no any solution found, and attachment

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this issue is to save the LibreOffice Impress file in its native **ODP** extension, on your Linux system. After you do that, access your Windows system, download and install the [LibreOffice suite for Windows 7](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=win-x86_64), then run it in order to open your ODP file on Windows 7.

An alternative to this - in case you **don't** need to edit the presentation file on Windows - is to use your Linux's LibreOffice Impress to export the presentation as a **PDF** file, so you can then open it and switch it to "presentation mode", which is nice if you want to use it e.g. on a business meeting.

Concerning tables, pictures, polygons and other objects present in LibreOffice files (drawings, texts, presentations et cetera), there are known long-term issues that occur while LibreOffice converts to the Microsoft Office format (DOC, DOCX, PPT, PPTX, XLS, XLSX et cetera) files that contain such objects. Thus, it's wise to avoid attempting such conversions. Not even iWork (Apple's office suite) succeeds 100% when it tries to open (or convert) Microsoft Office files.

PS: also notice that although PPTX is a "XML PPT" and thus it uses an open source format, traditionally Open Office and its forks (LibreOffice included) deal better with **PPT** files than with PPTX files. Thus, you should definitely give the PPT extension a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can try exporting the presentation to a PDF, where you can simply click through each slide. `File -> Export to PDF` This is what I would do, and it really is the only solution that doesn't involve a ton of re-editing.

If you have time, you can also make sure that Powerpoint has the same fonts as Impress, that would solve some issues. Powerpoint and Impress are known to not work well together, even when trying to share versions. Powerpoint simply has more features and is more complex than Impress. In the future, use one or the other.

Another thing to mention. If you can use Libreoffice Impress on Windows (preferably the same version), you should. It will definitely work with the Impress presentation created in Ubuntu, just be sure to save it as the default ODP format, and open the file in Windows. This would preserve transitions and rendering ability on the Windows side of things - you could present directly from Impress on Windows (if needed).

Comment: Frist of all Thanks for your suggestion but when am insert some effects on PPT then export on PDF  how i can represent  effects in PDF.

Comment: When exporting to PDF, you can't replicate animations. You can only replicate animations if you present in the same program that you created them in. Rarely does powerpoint interact well with impress's animations.